# Could not publish to the server. java.lang.NullPointerException in Tomcat v8.0 Server

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

[image: Publishing tomcat v8.0 at localhost error]

While Developing Project I got this Error.I used Eclipse Mars and Tomcat v8.0 Server.Actually upto last Night it works good but next morning it shows this error block.Nothing to be displayed in console, Error is just display on pop up window.I didn't get proper solution,So please help me to solve this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.jst.common.internal.modulecore.IgnoreJavaInSourceFolderParticipant.shouldAddExportableFile(IgnoreJavaInSourceFolderParticipant.java:64)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.shouldAddComponentFile(FlatVirtualComponent.java:288)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.VirtualComponentFlattenUtility.addFile(VirtualComponentFlattenUtility.java:122)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.VirtualComponentFlattenUtility.addMembersInternal(VirtualComponentFlattenUtility.java:99)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.VirtualComponentFlattenUtility.addMembersInternal(VirtualComponentFlattenUtility.java:96)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.VirtualComponentFlattenUtility.addMembers(VirtualComponentFlattenUtility.java:51)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.treeWalk(FlatVirtualComponent.java:230)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.cacheResources(FlatVirtualComponent.java:188)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.fetchResources(FlatVirtualComponent.java:118)
at org.eclipse.wst.web.internal.deployables.FlatComponentDeployable.members(FlatComponentDeployable.java:227)
at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.deployables.J2EEFlexProjDeployable.members(J2EEFlexProjDeployable.java:267)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.ModulePublishInfo.fillCache(ModulePublishInfo.java:314)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.ModulePublishInfo.getDelta(ModulePublishInfo.java:396)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.ServerPublishInfo.getDelta(ServerPublishInfo.java:366)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.getPublishedResourceDelta(Server.java:1578)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.getPublishedResourceDelta(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:698)
at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatServerBehaviour.getPublishedResourceDelta(TomcatServerBehaviour.java:958)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.computeDelta(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:874)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:909)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3172)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:345)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Comment: Have a look in your eclipse log. This is typically inside `workspace/.metadata/.log`. It will contain (near the bottom of the file) the stack trace for this exception, most likely is a problem in Eclipse. Perhaps from the stack trace you get a hint, if not please post the full stack trace here. Other things you can try is "right-click / refresh" on your project, and/or a "build / clean".

Comment: This is full stack trace .....

Comment: "build/clean" works for me!! Thank you......

Comment: hey I got same exception as above mentioned and this time "build/clean " not working , after "build/clean" it give another tomcat publishing error like "Removing obsolete files from server...Could not clean server of obsolete files: Content is not allowed in prolog." now what do I do??? please Help me..!!

Comment: better open a new question and post the stack trace there. from the first looks of it you have an error in some XML file, it doesn't start with `<?xml...?>`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, it turns out that for some reason Windows (or me) had made the Tomcat publish folder read only. I just removed that and the problem were solved.